# Python Selenium text extract list output from for loop

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, web-scraping

I am using Python/Selenium to extract some text from a website to further sort it in Google Sheets.

There are 15 headers for which I need to extract text. The text is found under each header in tag h5.

Here's one extract of a header:

```
<tr class="dayHeader"><td colspan="7" style="padding:10px 0;"><hr><h5>&nbsp;&nbsp;Thursday - 28 January 2021</h5></td></tr>
  <td colspan="7" style="padding:10px 0;"><hr><h5>&nbsp;&nbsp;Thursday - 28 January 2021</h5></td>
    <hr>
    <h5>&nbsp;&nbsp;Thursday - 28 January 2021</h5>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

What I have done is the following:

```
headers = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('h5')
results = []

for header in headers:
    result = header.text
    results.append(result)
```

The for loop above outputs the following list:

```
['Result 1']
['Result 1', 'Result 2']
['Result 1', 'Result 2', 'Result 3']
```

Instead, how can I get it to output:

```
['Result 1', 'Result 2', 'Result 3']
```

Comment: The above for loop shouldn't be outputting anything... did you miss a `print` statement when you copied your code over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A wrong indent of your `print` put it out of your loop like:

```
headers = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('h5')
results = []

for header in headers:
    result = header.text
    results.append(result)

print(results)
```

Will only print ones:

```
['Result 1', 'Result 2', 'Result 3']
```

instead of :

```
headers = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('h5')
results = []

for header in headers:
    result = header.text
    results.append(result)
    print(results)
```

Will every iteration print:

```
['Result 1']
['Result 1', 'Result 2']
['Result 1', 'Result 2', 'Result 3']
```

Comment: Of course! How could I not see this. Thanks for your help!